# Is there a way to automate the tag version of an image through gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, yaml

I want to do an increment to the image's tag for every commit in the branch by 1.

For example

First commit: the version is v1.0.1

the second commit : v1.0.1 (which v1.0.1 + 1)

Any idea on how can I automatically generate release tag?

Example of yaml

```
stages:
  - build-docker-image

docker-build:
  
  image: docker:20.10.16
  stage: build-docker-image
  
  script:
    - |
      if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ]]; then
        tag=""
        echo "Running on default branch '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH': tag = 'latest'"
      else
        tag=":v1.0.1"
        echo "Running on branch '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH': tag = $tag"
      fi
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}"
  # Run this job in a branch where a Dockerfile exists
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      exists:
        - Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git rev-list --count <root-branch>..HEAD` and use the returned value as the final digit in you version number.

`<root-branch>` is the branch from which the current branch was created. It will most often be `master`, `main` or `develop`.

Exemple: `echo "1.0."$(git rev-list --count main..HEAD)`

It will start with 0 and will increment with each new commit on your branch.

The drawback of this solution is that squashes performed on the current branch will reduce the number of commits leading to your version number going back - so it is best to use this technique on stable/protected branches only.